# Invisible scrollbars on a position:absolute div on Safari 5 for Windows

Tags: safari, css

I have a single div element in a page styled as follow:

```
div {position: absolute; width: 340px; height: 480px; overflow-y:scroll}
```

I use a simple jquery script to center it in the available width and height on window.resize event.

The div is displayed and works perfectly on Safari 5 for Mac.

On Safari 5 for Windows it works perfectly (i can scroll the content using the mouse wheel) but the vertical scrollbar is not rendered.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use jquery to center, just use the following:

```
div {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 340px; 
    height: 480px; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; 
    margin-top: -240px; 
    margin-left: -170px;
}
```

Maybe the scrollbar is not rendered because it's disabled (there's no more content), otherwise try with overflow-y:auto

Comment: I'll try...there's always enough content to have a scroll...tnx

Comment: Still no scrollbar...that's crazy

Comment: Umm... crazy :/ I'll try it at home